# Let $D \subseteq X$ be infinite subset of $X$ and every infinite subset of $D$ has infinite number of accumulations points in $X$........

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be countable and $T_B$( every compact subset is closed).

Let $D \subseteq X$ be infinite subset of $X$ and every infinite subset of $D$ has infinite number of accumulations points in $X$.

Suppose $n_0 \in \omega $be the smallest integer s.t ‎$ ‎x‎_{n‎_{0}‎}‎‎ $ is an accumulation point in $D$.

**So,**

> If $V$ is a **neighborhood** at ‎$ ‎x‎_{n‎_{0}‎}‎‎ $  and $D - V$  is **finite**, will every enumeration like $ \{ y_n  : n \in \omega \}$ of $D$ **converge to** ‎$ ‎x‎_{n‎_{0}‎}‎‎ $ ?

Comment: No such set $D$ can exist. Being countable, $X$ is hereditarily Lindelöf, and every hereditarily Lindelöf $T_B$ space has the $FDS$ property. In any case the question doesn’t really make sense: $X$ is a nbhd of $x_{n_0}$, and $D\setminus X$ is finite, but that says nothing about whether enumerations of $D$ converge to $x_{n_0}$.

Comment: It is part of "Lemma 8 from Spaces in which compact subsets are closed and the lattice of $T_1$-topologies on a set
by Ofelia T. Alas.**If $X$ is a countable $T_B$-space, then every infinite $D \subseteq X$ contains
an infinite subset with only a nite number of accumulation points (in X)**

Comment: The stronger result that every hereditarily Lindelöf $T_B$ space has the $FDS$ property is Theorem $1.10$ of Alas, Tkachenko, Tkachuk, & Wilson, ‘The $FDS$-property and spaces in which compact sets are closed’, if you want to see it. // You want $D\setminus V$ to be finite for **every** nbhd $V$ of $x_{n_0}$; what you actually wrote just says that there is one such nbhd of $x_{n_0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $D\setminus V$ is finite for each open nbhd $V$ of $x_{n_0}$. Let $\{y_n:n\in\omega\}$ be any enumeration of $D$. If $V$ is an open nbhd of $x_{n_0}$, $D\setminus V$ is finite, so there is an $m\in\omega$ such that $y_n\in V$ whenever $n\ge m$. Thus, the sequence $\langle y_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ is eventually inside every open nbhd of $x_{n_0}$, which by definition means that it converges to $x_{n_0}$.

Comment: How can we choose  a such  $m\in\omega$ such that $y_n\in V$ whenever $n\ge m$? Thanks.

Comment: @Ebi: Oh, come on: that’s easy. There are only finitely many $n\in\omega$ such that $y\in\notin V$. Suppose, for instance, that $D\setminus V$ turned out to be $\{y_0,y_4,y_5,y_{20}\}$; what could you use for $m$?